# Recommendations for attic decking

Tags: pipe, attic

My wife has been wanting me to add attic decking for a while. I went up again today to scope out what work is needed. My attic is full of supports, a/c ductwork and these metal pipes.

What are these metal pipes along the floor? I turned on cold/hot water around the house and hear nothing. It seems to run to more places than just my gas line and water heater. Also, what do you recommend for trying to deck some of this space?

[image: ac ducts]
[image: metal pipe]
[image: roof support]

Comment: They look like pipes for water or gas.  Age of house might narrow it down since steel for water not used much anymore.  Bare water pipes in an attic in cold winter weather not a good idea.  Have a fire sprinkler system?  Search for one end of a pipe might help seeing what it is for.

Comment: How old is the house [& where in the world]? If it's old enough that cast piping could be for gas lighting - you might find small drops to the old valves if so. You'd then have to  get a professional in to test & cap it further back, if it is. [idk about where you are but it's illegal (not just against building regs, actually illegal) to DIY gas in the UK].

Comment: 1960s. You’re right, the closest wall goes directly over our gas stove. So these are likely gas lines. The other lines head towards external gas and our gas fireplaces.

Comment: 60s wouldn't be for gas lighting, so chances are it's still live. Proceed with caution/expert assistance.

Comment: I’m not looking to move them, but I do want to make a deck to walk up there. It would be much harder to have to raise the floor for these pipes, perhaps I can just build around them

Answer (score 2):

If it were my attic I would raise the decking above all the piping and ductwork. Using the example that is already in place, but using a plywood gussets instead of a metal ones, and screws to hold everything together so the vibration of nailing does not shake the drywall fasteners.

[image]

The red circled block is the example I am referring to.

Use 4 ft. or longer if you can get them up there, cutting as needed to get around pipes etc. Figure your highest pipe in the way and go from there, maybe 2X4s will do it. Maybe it will take 2X6s.

Do be mindful how much you store up there, truss roofs are not designed to be a storage area, so no books or anything heavy concentrated in one spot.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging books are one of the heaviest things that can be stored up there.  (Empty suitcases, Christmas decorations, etc. much better.)